# mask a python list/array with mask values from a list - with if/else

Tags: python

we can mask a list with boolean values from another list with

```
arr = [1,2,3]
mask = [True, True, False]
[a for a, m in zip(arr, mask) if m]
```

I would like the result to be

```
arr = [1,2,3]
mask = [True, True, False]
```

gives

```
>>> [1,2,'.']
```

do you have an elegant one liner ?

Comment: Use `a if m else '.'` as the comprehension expression?

Comment: `[a if m else '.' for a, m in zip(arr, mask)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas dataframe where seems to do that

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html

```
The signature for DataFrame.where() differs from numpy.where(). 
Roughly df1.where(m, df2) is equivalent to np.where(m, df1, df2).
```